# Need alternatives to [blocking] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta-tags

I call your attention to the [blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocking) tag.

I see questions in there about blocking applications, calls, SMS messages, and processes.

That's no good.

I suggest the following replacements:

- [call-blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-blocking)
- [sms-blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms-blocking)
- <s>[app-blocking]</s>

The one about processes is an outlier. I don't think "blocking" is an appropriate tag/descriptor.

I also suggest that [blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocking) be a synonym for [call-blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-blocking) as that is how it is used most often. We don't want people to use the [blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocking) tag anymore.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: We have a [tag:call-screening] tag as well, seems to me call-blocking is just a subset of call-screening? I'm not sure we'd even allow that app-blocking question these days, seems a better fit for SuperUser?

Comment: Hmmm...call-screening and call-blocking are **awfully** similar. I suppose one could suss out the minor difference between _blocking_ and _screening_, but won't most people just use them synonymously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes a lot of sense to split these up sensibly, I'd propose something like this

- [call-screening](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-screening) <- [call-blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-blocking)*
- [sms-blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms-blocking)

Do we really need an [app-blocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-blocking) tag? The one question that I think you're nominating for it, is really a PC question rather than an Android one (and quite an edge case even there) I'd think it would be better off on SuperUser than here, and even then I think "locking" is probably closer to what is happening than blocking (seems to be to do with locked handles on mounted drives/files).

*I'd think that call-blocking should be set to a synonym of call-screening (as surely blocking is just a type of screening where you don't allow the call through after screening it). One of the call-screening questions even mentions blocking in the title.

Comment: I like your modifications. I will make it so.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a great idea and you should make it so!

If you need any tags destroyed in the process just let me know.